# How to become root or part of the sudoers group inside a DB2 Docker container?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I've created a DB2 container following [this guide](https://ajstorm.medium.com/installing-db2-on-your-coffee-break-5be1d811b052).

I now want to restore a sample database like [Books Database](https://www.db2tutorial.com/getting-started/create-db2-sample-database/) or [GSDB Sample Database](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/data-studio/4.1.1?topic=samples-gsdb-sample-database).

I copied the 2 folders containing the databases within the container with the commands:

```
docker cp /volume2/data/books/ 9cd8080b7c41:/mnt/books
docker cp /volume2/data/GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3/ 9cd8080b7c41:/mnt/GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3
```

I now have the 2 database sample inside `/mnt/books` and `/mnt/GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3`

But when I try to enter in one of the two directory with `cd GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3/` I receive the `error -bash: cd: GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3/: Permission denied`

These are my privileges with `ls -l`:

```
d--------- 1 1026 users     6 Jun  8 20:35 GSDB_DB2_LUW_ZOS_v2r3
d--------- 1 1026 users    52 Jun  8 20:35 books
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  76576 Jun 10  2019 books.zip
```

How to become root or make my user `db2inst1` to be part of the sudoers group inside a DB2 Docker container?

> EDIT: after @mustaccio comment

I tried to mount the directory with

```
docker run -v /volume2/data/books/:/mnt/books  -e LICENSE=accept -t ibmcom/db2 /bin/bash
```

unfortunately I receive this error:

```
LIC1426I  This product is now licensed for use as outlined in your License Agreement.  USE OF THE PRODUCT CONSTITUTES ACCEPTANCE OF THE TERMS OF THE IBM LICENSE AGREEMENT, LOCATED IN THE FOLLOWING DIRECTORY: "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5/license/en_US.iso88591"
(*) Saving the checksum of the current nodelock file ...
(*) Updating DBM CFG parameters ...
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
successfully.
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
successfully.
DB20000I  The UPDATE DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION command completed
successfully.
No Cgroup memory limit detected, instance memory will follow automatic tuning
(*) Remounting /database with suid...
mount: /database: cannot remount /dev/vg1000/lv read-write, is write-protected.

DB2 State : Operable
DB2 has not been started
Starting DB2...

06/09/2022 07:23:20     0   0   SQL1220N  The database manager failed to allocate shared memory.
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519
(*) All databases are now active.
(*) Setup has completed.
false

2022-06-09-07.23.20.319216+000 I21293E393            LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 13165                TID : 139941267707776 PROC : db2start
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: d4649de98dc6
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleReleaseStStLockFile, probe:16187
MESSAGE : Released lock on the file:
DATA #1 : String, 50 bytes
/database/config/db2inst1/sqllib/ctrl/db2strst.lck
```

I think the most interesting part of the log is this:

```
mount: /database: cannot remount /dev/vg1000/lv read-write, is write-protected.
```

Again, I cannot do stuff because I'm not root.

So how to be root?

Comment: You probably should just mount your samples inside the container as `--volume`s instead of copying them.

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio, I added a few logs. The problem persists. There must be a way to be root in DB2, right?

Answer (score 0):

I now know how to become `root`: use the official CLI provided by Docker!

Press on Create and a bash shell will be automatically prompted with root privileges.

[image]

Or you can login as root through

```
docker exec -it db2 bash -c "su - root"
```